# Managed Plugin for Unity 2017

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

I've been creating, or at least attempting to create a managed plugin for Unity.  So basically the idea is that the managed library contains necessary UWP code for communicating with Bluetooth devices that I would only like to use for UWP builds of my app.  I've created the placeholder plugin using Unity .net 3.5 full base classes framework, the placeholder contains no code and is just matching public interface code.

I can run the application in the Unity editor just fine, but obviously my UWP plugin isn't supported there so I need to do a UWP build, when I try to do so, I get these odd errors,

**WARNING, THIS IS THE LONGEST ERROR MESSAGE EVER**

```
Reference Rewriter found some errors while running with command --target="Temp\StagingArea\Assembly-CSharp.dll" --additionalreferences="Temp\StagingArea","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17134.0\Facade","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.AI.MachineLearning.Preview.MachineLearningPreviewContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.CallsVoipContract\3.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.SocialInfo.SocialInfoContract\2.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTaskContract\3.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Devices.Custom.CustomDeviceContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Devices.DevicesLowLevelContract\3.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Devices.Printers.PrintersContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Devices.SmartCards.SmartCardBackgroundTriggerContract\3.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Devices.SmartCards.SmartCardEmulatorContract\5.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\3.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\6.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Gaming.XboxLive.StorageApiContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Graphics.Printing3D.Printing3DContract\4.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Networking.Connectivity.WwanContract\2.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Services.Store.StoreContract\3.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Services.TargetedContent.TargetedContentContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.System.Profile.ProfileHardwareTokenContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.System.Profile.ProfileSharedModeContract\2.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ViewManagementViewScalingContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivatedEventsContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationCameraSettingsContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ContactActivatedEventsContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.WebUISearchActivatedEventsContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundAlarmApplicationContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.Background.CallsBackgroundContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.LockScreenCallContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Preview.InkWorkspace.PreviewInkWorkspaceContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Preview.Notes.PreviewNotesContract\2.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Management.ResourceIndexerContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.Core.SearchCoreContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Wallet.WalletContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Devices.Portable.PortableDeviceContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Devices.Printers.Extensions.ExtensionsContract\2.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Devices.Scanners.ScannerDeviceContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Devices.Sms.LegacySmsApiContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Gaming.Input.GamingInputPreviewContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Gaming.Preview.GamesEnumerationContract\2.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Gaming.UI.GameChatOverlayContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Gaming.UI.GamingUIProviderContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Globalization.GlobalizationJapanesePhoneticAnalyzerContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Management.Deployment.Preview.DeploymentPreviewContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Management.Workplace.WorkplaceSettingsContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Media.AppBroadcasting.AppBroadcastingContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Media.AppRecording.AppRecordingContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Media.Capture.AppBroadcastContract\2.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Media.Capture.AppCaptureContract\4.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Media.Capture.AppCaptureMetadataContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Media.Capture.GameBarContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Media.Devices.CallControlContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Media.MediaControlContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Media.Playlists.PlaylistsContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Media.Protection.ProtectionRenewalContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.LegacyNetworkOperatorsContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Networking.Sockets.ControlChannelTriggerContract\3.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Networking.XboxLive.XboxLiveSecureSocketsContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Perception.Automation.Core.PerceptionAutomationCoreContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Security.EnterpriseData.EnterpriseDataContract\5.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Services.Maps.GuidanceContract\3.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Services.Maps.LocalSearchContract\4.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Storage.Provider.CloudFilesContract\2.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.System.Profile.SystemManufacturers.SystemManufacturersContract\2.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.System.Profile.ProfileRetailInfoContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.System.UserProfile.UserProfileContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.System.UserProfile.UserProfileLockScreenContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.ApplicationsSettingsContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.UI.Core.AnimationMetrics.AnimationMetricsContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindowDialogsContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.UI.Xaml.Hosting.HostingContract\2.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Web.Http.Diagnostics.HttpDiagnosticsContract\2.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.System.SystemManagementContract\5.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.CallsPhoneContract\4.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.CommunicationBlocking.CommunicationBlockingContract\2.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Embedded.DeviceLockdown.DeviceLockdownContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorsFdnContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Phone.PhoneContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Phone.StartScreen.DualSimTileContract\1.0.0.0","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.UI.WebUI.Core.WebUICommandBarContract\1.0.0.0" --platform="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17134.0\Facade\Windows.winmd" --dbg=pdb --support="Temp\StagingArea\WinRTLegacy.dll" --supportpartialns=Unity.Partial --system=System --lock=UWP\project.lock.json --alt=System.Xml.Serialization;System.Collections,System.Collections.NonGeneric;System.Reflection,System.Reflection.TypeExtensions;System.IO,System.IO.FileSystem;System.Net,System.Net.Primitives;System.Net.Sockets,System.Net.Primitives;System.Xml,System.Xml.XmlDocument;<winmd>,Windows.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.AI.MachineLearning.Preview.MachineLearningPreviewContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.CallsVoipContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.SocialInfo.SocialInfoContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTaskContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Devices.Custom.CustomDeviceContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Devices.DevicesLowLevelContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Devices.Printers.PrintersContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Devices.SmartCards.SmartCardBackgroundTriggerContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Devices.SmartCards.SmartCardEmulatorContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Gaming.XboxLive.StorageApiContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Graphics.Printing3D.Printing3DContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Networking.Connectivity.WwanContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Services.Store.StoreContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Services.TargetedContent.TargetedContentContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.System.Profile.ProfileHardwareTokenContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.System.Profile.ProfileSharedModeContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ViewManagementViewScalingContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivatedEventsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationCameraSettingsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ContactActivatedEventsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.WebUISearchActivatedEventsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundAlarmApplicationContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.Background.CallsBackgroundContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.LockScreenCallContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Preview.InkWorkspace.PreviewInkWorkspaceContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Preview.Notes.PreviewNotesContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Management.ResourceIndexerContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.Core.SearchCoreContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Wallet.WalletContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Devices.Portable.PortableDeviceContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Devices.Printers.Extensions.ExtensionsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Devices.Scanners.ScannerDeviceContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Devices.Sms.LegacySmsApiContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Gaming.Input.GamingInputPreviewContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Gaming.Preview.GamesEnumerationContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Gaming.UI.GameChatOverlayContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Gaming.UI.GamingUIProviderContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Globalization.GlobalizationJapanesePhoneticAnalyzerContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Management.Deployment.Preview.DeploymentPreviewContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Management.Workplace.WorkplaceSettingsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.AppBroadcasting.AppBroadcastingContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.AppRecording.AppRecordingContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.Capture.AppBroadcastContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.Capture.AppCaptureContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.Capture.AppCaptureMetadataContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.Capture.GameBarContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.Devices.CallControlContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.MediaControlContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.Playlists.PlaylistsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.Protection.ProtectionRenewalContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.LegacyNetworkOperatorsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Networking.Sockets.ControlChannelTriggerContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Networking.XboxLive.XboxLiveSecureSocketsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Perception.Automation.Core.PerceptionAutomationCoreContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Security.EnterpriseData.EnterpriseDataContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Services.Maps.GuidanceContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Services.Maps.LocalSearchContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Storage.Provider.CloudFilesContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.System.Profile.SystemManufacturers.SystemManufacturersContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.System.Profile.ProfileRetailInfoContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.System.UserProfile.UserProfileContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.System.UserProfile.UserProfileLockScreenContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.ApplicationsSettingsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.UI.Core.AnimationMetrics.AnimationMetricsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindowDialogsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.UI.Xaml.Hosting.HostingContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Web.Http.Diagnostics.HttpDiagnosticsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.System.SystemManagementContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.CallsPhoneContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.CommunicationBlocking.CommunicationBlockingContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Embedded.DeviceLockdown.DeviceLockdownContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorsFdnContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Phone.PhoneContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Phone.StartScreen.DualSimTileContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.UI.WebUI.Core.WebUICommandBarContract.winmd --ignore=System.IConvertible,mscorlib.
Error: type `devoctomy.Unity.Plugins.DFramework.Loggin<message truncated>
```

I'm getting a whole lot of these, and really struggling to get rid of them, and I've changed my plugin quite a few times now, now the public interfaces is very basic so that the placeholder plugin fits in nicely, but it's the UWP one that's having issues here.

Comment: Have you tried switching to .NET 4.x?

Comment: Yup, back and forth, I'm trying again now, this time it's moaning about Tasks being used, so I'm seeing if I can remove / replace all references to those for Iasyncoperation.  Which I very much doubt will work too.

Comment: Saying that, it seems like that might not even be possible as you need to use Task to create an Iasyncoperation, or an IDispatcher, which I can't get in a class library afaik.  It seems there isn't actual UWP support, more metro support in Unity, is that correct?